# Zend Framework 1.11.2 cache_dir not writable

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have inherited an application written with Zend Framework 1.11.2. It has been ported to a server managed by my company, but some of the functionality of the site seem broken on the new server, due to a little fine tuning of the environment.

Specifically, one of the cron jobs on the system is throwing an exception related to the cache directory not being writable.

I am not sure where the cache directory is to make it writable. I have done a little reading and it seems to suggest there is a tmp directory. Can anyone point me in the right direction to either the directory, or how to find out where it is, if it is application specific?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure there is a path in the exception description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for which determines the `cache_dir` to use when one is not specified is in `Zend_Cache_Backend::getTmpDir()`. The results are OS-specific and even environment-specific.

This little snippet:

```
require_once 'Zend/Cache/Backend.php';
$cache = new Zend_Cache_Backend();
echo $cache->getTmpDir() . PHP_EOL;
```

produced `/tmp` on my Ubuntu. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

The cache directory is specified in *application.ini*:

- resources.cachemanager.database.backend.options.cache_dir
- resources.cachemanager.locale.backend.options.cache_dir
- resources.cachemanager.translations.backend.options.cache_dir

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request for this ([ZF-12214](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12214)). You can use the included patch to monkey-patch your ZF for debugging.